# New swift syntax for initialisation of SKNode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

So today I went back to coding after a while (half a year? plus before it wasn't like I was any good lol ...) and wanted to pickup Swift but this stopped me just before I even gave it a good try:

BTW I'm trying to make a "myWorld" variable that would act as the scene handler later on, well, u get the idea......

http://postimg.org/image/4n1izokcj/
(the error can't be seen here on stackoverflow, little resolution upload...)

the old Obj-C way that worked for me for initialising a new SKNode:

```
@interface Level() {
   SKNode* myWorld;
}

@implementation Level

-void setUpScene {
   myWorld = [SKNode node]
   [self addChild:myWorld]
}
```

the new Swift way that I thought should work:

```
var myWorld:SKNode?

class Level:SKScene {

   func setUpScene() {
      myWorld = SKNode.node()
      self.addChild(myWorld!)
   }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? (the "myWorld! = SKNode.node()" does the same...)

pls no flame.

thx for any constructive reply ^__^

Comment: I believe you have to unwrap SKNode with a `!`.  Try using `SKNode!.node()`

Comment: In the obj-c example, myWorld is an instance variable. IN your swift code it is a global variable. You should put var myWorld:SKNode? inside your class declaration, if you want it to be an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm just blind... the syntax is

```
myWorld = SKNode()
```

& not

```
myWorld = SKNode.node()
```

jeez... feel free to erase this question editors...